# Empirical distribution using R

Tags: r, probability, distributions, computational-statistics

I have a data frame that shows the actions and status of a project in two fields.I am going to use Empirical distribution to find the real probability not theoretical probability. I found that I can use Empirical Distribution function to find the probability. How can I calculate the probability of occurring different status correspond to different actions using Empirical distribution function.

```
 action = c("a1", "a1", "a2","a1") 
 status = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,FALSE) 
 df = data.frame(a,s) 

 action status
1     a1  TRUE
2     a1 FALSE
3     a2  TRUE
4     a1 FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contingency table of relative frequencies will give you the empirical
joint probability distribution.

```
> tab <- table(df)
> addmargins(prop.table(tab))

      status
action FALSE TRUE  Sum
   a1   0.50 0.25 0.75
   a2   0.00 0.25 0.25
   Sum  0.50 0.50 1.00
```

If you need more sophisticated, you can estimate standard errors using the
bootstrap method.